# Why do I have to assign the external function to a variable before I can invoke it?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

Why isn't this working as expected?

```
function external() {    
    function internal() {
        alert("external");
    }
    return internal;
}
external(); //nothing happens

var func = external();
func(); // alert pops up
```

does it have to do with the fact, that it's a closure? Because here it works like I expect it would:

```
function test() {
     alert("test");   
}
test(); //alert pops up without assigning the function to a variable
```

Comment: When you do `external();` you are getting the `internel` function object, you need to explicitly invoke that, may be, like this `external()();`

Comment: yes! did the trick! i found this as an example in a javascript book and was wondering why they assigned it first ... JS is sometimes hard to understand ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @thefourtheye suggested when i just do

```
external();
```

only the internel function object gets returned.

I just added an example to make it more clear!

```
function external() {    
    alert("foo");
    function internal() {
        alert("bar");
    }
    return internal;
}
external(); //returns foo (and the internel function)
external()(); //return foo and then bar
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `return internal`, it is returning a function. The function is NOT executed, merely passed as a reference back to the caller of the external function. So `external()` basically evaluates to a function expression that is not executed. It is effectively equivalent to writing:

```
function() {
    alert("external");
}
```

Nothing happens, because the function is simply expressed but never executed.

Contrastingly, for `var func = external();`, the function expression is assigned to variable `func`. In effect, it is equivalent to writing:

```
var func = function() {
    alert("external");
}
```

This is why when you execute `func()` subsequently, the alert pops up.